# Not giving unique random value in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
    local i = nil
    local randNum = nil
    local tableSize = nil
    local gap = 300
    local t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    local tableSize = 5


    for i=1,5,1 do
        randNum = t[mRandom(tableSize)] 
        table.remove(t, randNum)

        if randNum == 1 then
            pencilOne.x = 680 + (gap*i)
            pencilTwo.x = 680 + (gap*i)
        end
        if randNum == 2 then
            scissor.x = 680 + (gap*i)
        end
        if randNum == 3 then
            paperClip.x = 680 + (gap*i)
        end
        if randNum == 4 then
            inkPot.x = 680 + (gap*i)
        end
        if randNum == 5 then
            gum.x = 680 + (gap*i)
        end

        tableSize = tableSize - 1

    end
```

I was trying to get a unique random value after each iteration. I am using the table.remove technique to get it done. I dont know why it is not giving me the unique random value. kindly, help. :)

Answer (score 4):

These lines extract a value from the table, and then wrongly use the value *itself* as an index to `table.remove`:

```
    randNum = t[mRandom(tableSize)] 
    table.remove(t, randNum)
```

What you really want to write is:

```
    randIndex = mRandom(tableSize)
    randNum = t[randIndex]
    table.remove(t, randIndex)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line:

> randNum = t[mRandom(tableSize)]

Lets suppose on the first iteration you get a random roll of 1.
randNum value gets calculated as:

```
randNum = t[1]
randNum = 1
```

Then the next statement removes the 2nd entry from the table. In this case, the table becomes:

> t = {2, 3, 4, 5}

On the next iteration, the random function range is from 1-4. Lets assume the new rolled number is 4. Now randNum is calculated as:

```
randNum = t[4]
randNum = 5
```

The next statement tried to remove the 5th entry from the table. Which does not exist. So your code won't work properly.

In order to solve the problem, you can change the random number generation with the following code:

```
randSize = mRandom(tableSize)
randNum  = t[randSize]
table.remove(t, randSize)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, Hunter Seeker. Got the bug. ;)